# XNA Object not changing

Tags: c#, xna

I have an object which if it gets to a certain state, I create a new object:

```
        if (currentShape.State == ShapeState.Landed)
        {
            Shape shape = new Shape();
            shape = utilities.GetRandomShape(contentManager);
            shapes.Add(shape);
            currentShape = shape;
        }
```

The object `currentShape` keeps changing in this manner. For some reason however, currentShape is still ShapeState.Landed forever.

The game which I have has objects falling, when one reaches the ground, another one is created and it is assigned to `currentShape`. So whenever `currentShape` lands, another one is created... as mentioned.

The logic for the Update method is as follows:

```
    public void Update(TimeSpan elapsedTime, List<Shape> shapes, Shape fallingShape)
    {
        List<Shape> shapesInSameColumn = new List<Shape>();

        foreach (var shape in shapes)
        {
            if (shape.ColumnNumber == fallingShape.ColumnNumber)
            {
                shapesInSameColumn.Add(shape);
            }
        }

        shapesInSameColumn.Remove(fallingShape);
        float yDestination = 0f;
        float yNextPosition = fallingShape.Position.Y + elapsedTime.Milliseconds / 30 * FallSpeed;

        if (shapesInSameColumn.Count == 0) // There are NO shapes in the column
        {
            yDestination = Utilities.bottomOfCanvas;
            if (yNextPosition > yDestination)
            {
                fallingShape.Position.Y = yDestination;
                fallingShape.State = ShapeState.Landed;
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                fallingShape.Position.Y = yNextPosition;
            }
        }
        else // There ARE shapes in the column
        {
            yDestination = shapesInSameColumn[shapesInSameColumn.Count - 1].Position.Y - Texture.Height;

            if (yNextPosition > yDestination)
            {
                fallingShape.Position.Y = yDestination;
                fallingShape.State = ShapeState.Landed;
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                fallingShape.Position.Y = yNextPosition;
            }
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**
After a few frames, it goes in to an endless loop of adding Shapes to the collection as the State is always Landed.

Comment: My guess is that, after the first code you provided runs, it then runs the `Update` method, where `fallingShape.State` is set to `Landed`.

Comment: ......Could you please elaborate what you mean/what you think the problem is?

Comment: Show the code for the object that runs the first code you provided. It's likely that it's executing that code, and then running the `Update` method.

Comment: State seem to be a property - just set break point in setter and see what code sets it to `Landed`....

Comment: Inside the Update method which I provided, it sets the State to landed... which is perfectly fine. The problem is that when I come back and create a new Shape... it's still landed. Even though the code that creates a new shape defaults to a Falling state and not landed.

Comment: @ShadowCat7 the GetRandomShape returns a new Shape with Falling as the state 100%.

Comment: Is the created shape `Landed` when it's not supposed to, or is the current shape?

Comment: The currentShape becomes the new Shapes when the previous one lands. Think of it like this, I have one shape and a list of shapes, the list of shapes has all the landed ones and the single shape is the currently falling one. So when the current one lands, I simply create a new shape and make the currentShape = newShape;

Comment: Perhaps you aren't changing `fallingShape` to represent(reference) the new shape and it is still referencing a landed shape. you may want to give each shape a unique serial number just while debugging to verify the shape that is being tested is the one you think should be tested for `yNextPosition`.

Comment: That might be it. I'll try that.

Comment: The only thing which might be going wrong is doing currentShape = newShape; since currentShape is at class level, would this break anything in terms of references? I have a collection of Shapes too which holds everything.

Answer (score 1):

This is what it sounds like you have (correct me if I'm mistaken):

```
public void Update(TimeSpan elapsedTime, List<Shape> shapes, Shape fallingShape)
    {
        List<Shape> shapesInSameColumn = new List<Shape>();

        //Added code.
        if (currentShape.State == ShapeState.Landed)
        {
            Shape shape = new Shape();
            shape = utilities.GetRandomShape(contentManager);
            shapes.Add(shape);
            currentShape = shape;
        }

        foreach (var shape in shapes)
        {
            if (shape.ColumnNumber == fallingShape.ColumnNumber)
            {
                shapesInSameColumn.Add(shape);
            }
        }

        shapesInSameColumn.Remove(fallingShape);
        float yDestination = 0f;
        float yNextPosition = fallingShape.Position.Y + elapsedTime.Milliseconds / 30 * FallSpeed;

        if (shapesInSameColumn.Count == 0) // There are NO shapes in the column
        {
            yDestination = Utilities.bottomOfCanvas;
            if (yNextPosition > yDestination)
            {
                fallingShape.Position.Y = yDestination;
                fallingShape.State = ShapeState.Landed;
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                fallingShape.Position.Y = yNextPosition;
            }
        }
        else // There ARE shapes in the column
        {
            yDestination = shapesInSameColumn[shapesInSameColumn.Count - 1].Position.Y - Texture.Height;

            if (yNextPosition > yDestination)
            {
                fallingShape.Position.Y = yDestination;
                fallingShape.State = ShapeState.Landed;
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                fallingShape.Position.Y = yNextPosition;
            }
        }
    }
```

So that means that it will still continue to update after the `//Added code` executes, correct? The fix is to not update if `currentShape.State == ShapeState.Landed`.